# Reduce redundant SQLite nested query?

Tags: sqlite, subquery, query-optimization

How can I reduce this nested query so that X,Y,Z are filtered prior to checking AA?
This works but is expensive since it calculates X,Y,Z for each subquery.
Only AA needs to be checked in each.

```
SELECT 3*b3.bin3 + 2*b2.bin2 + b1.bin1 FROM 
  (SELECT count(*) AS bin1 FROM `TD` WHERE
  `X` = 1 AND
  `Y` >= 2 AND
  `Z` >= 2 AND
  `AA` >= 1 AND `AA` <= 2) b1
  JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) AS bin2 FROM `TD` WHERE
  `X` = 1 AND
  `Y` >= 2 AND
  `Z` >= 2 AND
  `AA` >= 2.01 AND `AA` <= 3) b2
  JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) AS bin3 FROM `TD` WHERE
  `X` = 1 AND
  `Y` >= 2 AND
  `Z` >= 2 AND
  `AA` >= 3.01 AND `AA` <= 4) b3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you on SQL 2008? you might be able to use with as. Try this

```
With b as
(
Select
*
from TD
where 
x=1 and
y >= 2 and
z >= 2)

SELECT 3*b3.bin3 + 2*b2.bin2 + b1.bin1 FROM 

(select
count ()
from b
where AA >= 1 and AA <= 2) bin1
join

(select
count ()
from b
where AA >= 2.01 and AA <= 3) bin2
join

(select
count ()
from b
where AA >= 3.01 and AA <= 4) bin3
```

Comment: Also, if your data is more precise than 2 decimals, I might recommend the where line of bin2 to be:
where AA > 2 and AA <= 3
and the where line of bin3 to be:
where AA > 3 and AA <= 4

Comment: Thanks! That was the hint I needed. I'm using SQLite. My data is mostly floating point, but this was shown for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
--REDUCED FORM from Golden Ratio's hint.
WITH `v` AS
(SELECT `AA` FROM `TD` WHERE
  `X` = 1 AND
  `Y` >= 2 AND
  `Z` >= 2)
SELECT 3*bin3 + 2*bin2 + bin1 FROM
  (SELECT count(*) AS bin1 FROM `v` WHERE
  `AA` >= 1 AND `AA` <= 2)
  JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) AS bin2 FROM `v` WHERE
  `AA` >= 2.01 AND `AA` <= 3)
  JOIN
  (SELECT count(*) AS bin3 FROM `v` WHERE
  `AA` >= 3.01 AND `AA` <= 4);
```